# Como activar el modo IE en Microsoft Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer

Requiero abrir una pagina que solo funciona con Internet Explorer en el navegador Microsoft Edge, estoy siguiendo los pasos de ir a edge://flags y buscar “Enable IE Integration” para poder habilitar el botón "Abrir sitios web en modo Internet Explorer” pero ni siquiera aparece la característica.

Mi navegador se encuentra actualizado a la versión 91.0.864.41

Que se requiere para habilitar esa característica?, existe alguna otra alternativa para usar las características de IE en Microsoft Edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En los Settings del navegador, vas a *Navegador por defecto* y verás la opción para habilitar el recargar una página en modo de compatibilidad (está deshabilitado por defecto)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uno no debería estar moviendo los flags del navegador a menos que no haya cómo modificar las cosas en la interfaz estándar.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. El detalle es que no me aparece el interruptor. Encontré la solución, esta configuración solo esta disponible con Microsoft Edge para empresa. Un saludo.