# como forzar el modo compatibilidad de edge?

Tags: navegador-web

Tengo un problema al abrir el sistema de mi empresa ya que es un sw legado solo abre en IE11 y al abrirlo en modo compatibilidad de edge, no paso del login ya que me retira del modo compatibilidad, esto solo me pasa en w7, ya que en w10 me va de maravilla por el momento

Comment: Esto te sirve? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460421/como-activar-el-modo-ie-en-microsoft-edge

Answer (score 0):

también puedes utilizar el add-on "IE-Tab" para Google Chrome. Lo he utilizado sin problema en varias situaciones.

Te dejo el enlace: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=es-419

Espero te sea de utilidad.
Saludos

Comment: si eso he usado, pero me piden usar de manera nativa el modo compatibilidad en edge